# why am i getting undeclared variable error in blade (in laravel)?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am new in laravel and I try to make a it display on screen some information form my migration but it keeps giving me an error of undeclared variable in the "alunos" blade

this is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Models\Aluno;

class AlunoCoontroller extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $alunos = Aluno::all();

        return view('alunos',['alunos' => $alunos]);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('alunos.create');
    }

}
```

Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Aluno extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

migation

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('_alunos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('nome');
            $table->string('filme');
            $table->string('RA');
            $table->string('senha');
            $table->string('cpf');
            $table->string('cep');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     * 
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('_alunos');
    }
};
```

and the blade

```
@extends('layouts.main')
 
@section('title', 'Star-Fox Company')

@section('content')
    <h1>tela onde o aluno vai inserri os dados para acessar seu cadastro</h1>

    @foreach ($alunos as $aluno)
        <p>Nome: {{ $aluno->nome }}</p>
        <p>Matricula: {{ $aluno->filme }}</p>
        <p>Curso: {{ $aluno->curso }}</p>
        <p>Senha: {{ $aluno->senha }}</p>
        
    @endforeach

@endsection
```

I already try change the name of this variable but the error keeps, can someone help me with this
explaining why it giving an undeclared variable error on the blade

Comment: Can you add the full error message? (append to the question) ... in the blade there is a reference to `curso`, but I do not see this in the migration?

Comment: Illuminate
 \ 
Foundation
 \ 
Bootstrap
 \ 
HandleExceptions
 
: 8
handleError

Comment: Did you run the migration ? I don't see any properties in your model (either $guarded or $fillable)

Comment: yes I already running my migrations, how did I put properties to my model ?

Comment: This error could be something related to the routes ?

Comment: @GolfBravoSierra Check this doc: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-assignment Eloquent models are bound to a table, and you need to specify which columns should be filled by the ORM. Check the doc also for the table name inside model. Haven't used Laravel for ages, but solution definitely is in this direction

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `$aluno->curso` in your migration.

Answer (score 0):

I find where the problem was. I just forgot to config my routes, so they were past the variable to the blade file:

```php
Route::get('/area_do_aluno/{id}', [AlunoCoontroller::class, 'index'] );
```